# Invisible Mouse Cursor in Games

Tags: mouse, games, cursor

After I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I now have an invisible mouse cursor in some of my games. Specific example is Mount and Blade Warband. I definitely am not a power user so much help is needed. To be clear my mouse cursor is visible on the desktop, chrome,discord,and programs like steam but when I launch some of my games (not all of them) the mouse cursors turns invisible. I can still select stuff with it like it is there but I just can't see it.